Android OnTouchListener not working properly
I have an application when i need to show an image as an overlay just like in XRecorder app and when i click on it show / hide a certain , the issue that when app launches and i starting dragging , then i click show / hide layout until here it works fine , when i again try to drag , it does not drag and to add that when i log x and y , they are printed and show that values are changing when i drag with my finger but image itself is not dragging , any help would be appreciated , Thank you

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var cpuInfoContainer : LinearLayout
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var windowManager: WindowManager
    private lateinit var overlayView: View
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private lateinit var fpsMonitor: FPSMonitor

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            val intent =
                Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:$packageName"))
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1005)
        }

        showMain()

    }
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private fun showMain() {
        windowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        overlayView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null)
        val overlayImage = overlayView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.overlayImage)

        var isShown = false // Tracks if the secondary layout is shown
        var isDragging = false // Tracks if the overlay is being dragged
        var initialX = 0
        var initialY = 0
        var initialTouchX = 0f
        var initialTouchY = 0f
        val dragThreshold = 10 // Minimum drag threshold to be considered as drag

        val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.START
        params.x = 0
        params.y = 150

        // Add the overlay view to the WindowManager if not already added
        if (!overlayView.isAttachedToWindow) {
            windowManager.addView(overlayView, params)
        }

        // Resetting the touch listener on the image view
        overlayImage.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    // Record the initial positions of the overlay and touch
                    initialX = params.x
                    initialY = params.y
                    initialTouchX = event.rawX
                    initialTouchY = event.rawY
                    isDragging = false // Reset dragging state on new touch
                    true
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    // Calculate the change in position
                    val deltaX = (event.rawX - initialTouchX).toInt()
                    val deltaY = (event.rawY - initialTouchY).toInt()

                    // Check if the drag threshold is exceeded
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > dragThreshold || Math.abs(deltaY) > dragThreshold) {
                        isDragging = true // Set dragging flag to true
                        params.x = initialX + deltaX
                        params.y = initialY + deltaY

                        // Update the overlay position in the window manager
                        if (overlayView.isAttachedToWindow) {
                            windowManager.updateViewLayout(overlayView, params)
                        }
                    }
                    true
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    // Handle click action only if it was not a drag
                    if (!isDragging) {
                        // Toggle overlay visibility
                        if (isShown) {
                            removeOverlayLayout() // Remove the layout completely
                            isShown = false
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Overlay Hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        } else {
                            showOverlayLayout() // Add the layout back
                            displayCpuInfo()
                            isShown = true
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Overlay Shown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
                    isDragging = false // Reset dragging state after touch release
                    true
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                    isDragging = false // Reset dragging if touch event is canceled
                    true
                }

                else -> false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showOverlayLayout() {
        // Inflate the layout for the overlay view
        overlayView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.widget_layout, null)

        val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
            else
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        )
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP or Gravity.START
        windowManager.addView(overlayView, params)

        fpsMonitor = FPSMonitor(1000)
        fpsMonitor.startMonitoring()

        updateOverlay()
    }

    private fun removeOverlayLayout() {
        if (::overlayView.isInitialized && overlayView.isAttachedToWindow) {
            windowManager.removeView(overlayView)
        }
    }

    private fun updateOverlay() {

        val cpuTempView = overlayView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cpuTempValue)
        val gpuTempView = overlayView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.gpuTempValue)
        val gpuFanView = overlayView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.gpuFanValue)
        val batteryView = overlayView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.batteryValue)
        val batteryPercentage = overlayView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.batteryPercentage)
        val fpsView = overlayView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.fpsValues)
        val totalRam = overlayView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.totalRam)
        val usedRam = overlayView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ramUsed)
        val availableRam = overlayView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ramAvailable)
        cpuInfoContainer = overlayView.findViewById(R.id.cpuInfoContainer)

        handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                cpuTempView.text = getCpuTemperature()
                gpuTempView.text = getGpuTemperature()
                gpuFanView.text = getGpuFanSpeed()
                batteryView.text = getBatteryTemperature()
                batteryPercentage.text = buildString {
                    append(getBatteryPercentage().toString())
                    append("%")
                }
                fpsView.text = buildString {
                    append(fpsMonitor.calculateFPS().toString())
                    append(" FPS")
                }
                totalRam.text = getTotalRam()
                usedRam.text = getUsedRam()
                availableRam.text = getAvailableRam()

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
            }
        }, 1000)
    }




